# Publish Web wizard does not appear per microsoft's instructions

Tags: web, visual-studio-2012, publish

According to this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337.aspx), "right-click the project and select Publish (or Publish Web Site for web site projects) to open the Publish Web wizard".  What then comes up looks nothing like what is shown on that page, instead I get this: [image]
which looks nothing like the "Publish Web wizard" described on the MS page.  I have tried many of the options on that page, none of them lead to asking me to import my host's "publish profile".

Is there another way I can get to the Publish Web wizard so I can import my host's "publish profile"?

Comment: Can you show where you are right-clicking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try install this update: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj161045

I had the same problem. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the Publish Web wizard (just like the one that is shown in the link you provided) is only available for Web application projects, not for Web Site projects, whereas the screenshot in your original question is the tool provided in Visual Studio to publish web sites.
In my case, I found it useful to convert the web site project to a web application project following the suggestions given [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oAvBR2NPqmQ) and explained in detail at the LearnAsp4.com site.
Hope it helps someone :).

Comment: I don't know if this was once the case but a note to others it should work for Web Site projects in at least VS2015 or higher (I think I first started using it in VS2013).

Answer (score 0):

Hi download upgrade 5 for VS 2012 from Microsoft site and install the executable. Then VS 2012 will display the publish wizard as shown for web application.

Answer (score 0):

I had an existing publish profile under App_Data that had an invalid path in the pubxml, deleting that or fixing the path fixed it for me. I found this by going to "View > Other Windows > Web Publish Activity" then either select existing or try to create a new profile from the dropdown. This then gave me an error message which "Build > Publish Web App" didn't.